# How much will adding an extra hard drive to my MacBook Pro affect battery performance?

Tags: macbook-pro, hard-drive, hardware, performance

I have a current MacBook Pro 15" i7 2.2Ghz with a 500GB 7200RPM (default) hard drive.

I am thinking of replacing both the current hard drive and the superdrive with two [Seagate Momentus Hybrid 500 GB](http://www.seagate.com/www/en-us/products/laptops/laptop-hdd/) drives and placing them in RAID0 for optimal performance.

Now, I don't think performance will be a problem, but how about **battery life**? Are there any examples of users who already have done similar things and noticed the effect on battery life?

Comment: @cksum [RAID0 (a.k.a. Striping)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_RAID_levels#RAID_0) is typically done for performance, not redundancy (since it provides none).

Comment: Here is an article that may help you see just how much impact an HD has on a system in terms of power consumption: http://cl.ly/1h0y0g3V1r2n1m0n1V2g

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having a second hard drive will certainly decrease battery life by a noticeable amount. Behind the CPU and LCD, the hard drive is the largest drain on battery.

A word of caution: RAID 0 is almost never a good idea, unless you'll be doing backups constantly and don't mind being totally down if a drive fails. You'll get better performance from an SSD and you'll be able to keep your optical drive.

Comment: Or, if you need the space you can add an SSD as your boot and move your existing HD to the optical bay.

Comment: Do you have a source for your answer? This chart shows that hard drives are at the bottom of the power consumption ladder (comparable with RAM): http://www.pcpower.com/technology/power_usage/

Comment: @cksum considering that an optical drive is almost never in use and a 2nd hard drive in R0 by definition would always be in use, it's kind of obvious.

Comment: Mark, did you even visit the link I supplied? An HD's power consumption was ranked at the same level as 1-2 GB of RAM, which correct me if I'm wrong, are also always in use. So again, based on those numbers, why do you think you'd see a "dramatic" decrease to batter life? The question isn't so much whether the HD would be constantly in use, as it is about power consumption. A 5W fan always in use would be far less detrimental than a 30W fan in use half the time, would it not?

Comment: @MarkM +1 for caution about RAID 0, also known as "Scary RAID".

Comment: @cksum - I'm not sure what's so hard to understand what I'm saying. A device doesn't always draw the same amount of power just because it's in the system. If a DVD drive is idle, it will consume almost no power. If it's in use, it will consume more power. If a HDD is put into that slot, it will almost always be on, due to the fact that it's in a R0. That's an extra 15-30W draw *constantly* where there was almost no draw previously.

Comment: **"Behind the CPU and LCD, the hard drive is the largest drain on battery."** Clearly, from the data presented by pcpower, that's not true. I'm not debating whether it's a constant draw or not, but rather how much does 30W *affect* the battery life. You clearly have no data to support your initial assertion that it will be a **"noticeable amount."** Moreover, based on the figures from pcpower it looks like an extra HD would pull as much power as upgrading the system's RAM from 4 GB to 8 GB, something a lot of people are doing, and none of them are complaining about a "noticeable" battery drop.

Comment: @MarkM: Be nice or you will be banned. Please save the rants for other forums that are more accepting of that type of behavior.

Comment: @PhilipRegan other SE sites are very concerned about the factual accuracy of their data. If a user on SF, for example, posts something incorrect, other users feel **obligated** to point out the error as a curtosey to future visitors. I'm sorry if you thought that I was out of line, but someone posting out-of-whack desktop power consumption numbers from 4 years ago in a topic about a brand new notebook is just plain wrong. I know I have low rep here but I'm a 10k user on two of the original trilogy sites. By deleting my answer that rebutted **bad*** data, you did a disservice to the community.

Comment: @MarkM: It is one thing to post data refuting what you consider to be bad data or bad information, it is something else to make off-hand negative remarks in the process. You could have made your point without telling him to "go back to what he knows". Maybe the other SE sites you frequent tolerate that sort of tone, but it is not tolerated here. Questions and answers I will edit, but comments I will not. Welcome to the AD community. Be nice, and that includes to me as well. This is your first warning.

Comment: @cksum: The numbers provided on that site you linked are off by at least an order of magnitude. My system with 2TB of memory certainly does not consume 30kW by itself.

Comment: I make no claims as to the accuracy of that data. I used them in terms of percentages. Additionally, I am all for corrections. You'll see by my answers that I do in fact demand a level of factual support. With that said, I don't see how your site "beats" my site. What makes your link factually correct and mine wrong? I don't profess to be a hardware engineer at Apple. I'm just building a case of information I find. If I'm wrong, I'll certainly admit it. But I'll need a little more evidence than another link to some random site.

Comment: @cksum how can you possibly use desktop consumption numbers *from a PSU* vendor as a reference in a notebook power consumption discussion? Apple ships the notebooks with a 65W adapter. The entire system is designed not to exceed 65W under full load. I don't know what other proof you need? You're using apples to compare oranges.

Comment: ^ no pun intended

Comment: *"Behind the CPU and LCD, the hard drive is the largest drain on battery."* That's not true and that's what spurred my argument. Again, I used the numbers of a desktop in terms of percentages. Inexplicably, you don't want to hear that. Your arguments have derailed as a result; let's restore focus. Refer here: http://cl.ly/1h0y0g3V1r2n1m0n1V2g You'll see that HD power draw is comparable to RAM in most cases and when at full bore spikes to 15%. This would be rare however. Yet, it still falls under the GPU and other components. Data doesn't agree with you. HDs aren't *monster* power hungry.

Answer (score 0):

Go with an SSD. The lack of moving parts will *increase* battery life.

On my previous (late 2011) non-Retina MBP, I replaced the optical drive with a 512GB SSD, (The optical drive is basically useless 90% of the time - may as well use the space for SOMETHING.), and moved the operating system installations (OSX and Win7) to the SSD. This significantly improved battery life as well as overall performance.

If you don't want to pony up the cash for two large SSDs, put one SSD in along with a higher RPM spin drive.

Also, check out the Corsair 16GB RAM upgrade available from Newegg, among other places. Takes about 10 minutes to install, doesn't void your warranty, and also really helps overall performance.

Answer (score 0):

i wonder how well a hybrid will work in a raid0.
could there be some logic that would make the ssd portion of this hybrid useless when used as a raw raid0 drive?

i'm not sure about their logic of caching from spinning drive to the ssd portion.  but if it's by file name or structure, the raid-0'ness of it might defeat that.

just a thought